# Windows Server 2003 DHCP

Tags: dhcp, windows-server

I have a scenario where user had ip's 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.1.160 previously it was 192.168.1.10 to 192.168.1.254

The problem is that the ip of the users on 192.168.1.19 and 192.168.1.42 is not changing, what should I do? Do i need to release the ip address from DHCP and reassign it?

Answer (score 0):

Simple `ipconfig /release` followed by an `ipconfig /renew` in a command prompt should fix it. Let me know if it doesn't.